# Custom Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qt

How do I create a simple widget that would contain a first, middle and last name field and add it to the main window class?

I ask because I cant figure out why is this simple widget attempt below is not working, what have I missed?

main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainWindow class

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent){
    QMainWindow *mainView = new QMainWindow;
    setCentralWidget(mainView);

    CardUI *card = new CardUI;
    QHBoxLayout *hCard = new QHBoxLayout;

    hCard->addWidget(card);

    mainView->setLayout(hCard);
    mainView->show();
}
```

cardui class

```
CardUI::CardUI(QWidget *parent) :  QWidget(parent){
    QLineEdit *fnText = new QLineEdit;
    QLineEdit *miText = new QLineEdit;
    QLineEdit *lnText = new QLineEdit;

    QHBoxLayout *name = new QHBoxLayout;

    name->addWidget(fnText);
    name->addWidget(miText);
    name->addWidget(lnText);

    setLayout(name);
}
```

Comment: Your MainWindow constructor looks rather strange. Copy/paste issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QMainWindow *mainView = new QMainWindow;
//....
mainView->setLayout(hCard);
```

You *should not* change layout of `QMainWindow`. Use `setCentralWidget` or add toolbars/docks using given API instead.

In this particular case you shouldn't create `mainView` as `QMainWindow` (you cannot have two *main* windows in *one* application, right?). You can change `mainView` type to `QWidget`, but you can even don't create any proxy widgets, and just

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent); : QMainWindow(parent){   
    card = new CardUI;
    setCentralWidget(card);
}
```

Comment: You can have two (or more) `QMainWindows` in an application, in fact in Qt it's the only way to 'nest' toolbars/dockWidgets inside a child widget.  But on your main point I think you're right, it's definitely a code smell what the OP is doing in the main window constructor.

Comment: @cbamber85, I was considering impossibility of having 2 main windows from the semantics point of view. In this case code should follow semantics)